# Matlab OOP: Is it possible to return a property (value) of an object when evaluating it (overload default behaviour)?

Tags: matlab, oop, operator-overloading

Is is possible to create a user defined class that upon evaluation returns a value (property) instead of the default class info?

For example, I create a class *foo*:

```
classdef foo < handle

  properties
    val
  end

end
```

make and instance (object *o*) and assign a value to the property:

```
o = foo();
o.val = 1;
```

now, if I just evaluate *o* (for example type o and hit enter at the command prompt) I get:

```
>> o         

o = 

  foo with properties:

    val: 1
```

I would like to overload which ever evaluation method is called and return a property (in this case val) instead:

```
>> o         

o =

     1
```

To clarify, I would like to return a value as a variable not display a string, so that I can use it further. For example:

```
>> b = o;
>> b         

b =

     1
```

where `b` is a double with value 1. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: When you "evaluate" o in the workspace, MATLAB is just displaying the object. You can overload the built-in display method of the object with custom behavior.  Read about the display function.

Comment: Thanks, overloading display doesn't seem to permit output arguments though. I tired with adding a method:

`methods`
`  function out=display(obj)`
`     out = obj.val`
`  end`
`end`

but that didn't work.

Comment: @siliconwafer: `disp`-function not `dsiplay`-function

Answer (score 2):

You have to overload `disp`

```
classdef foo < handle

  properties
    val
  end
  methods
      function disp(obj)
          disp(obj.val)
      end
  end
end
```

For more advanced options check the documentation for [matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.customdisplay-class.html)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be quite it. If I do `a = foo(); a.val = 1; b = a;` and then just type `b` the output seems correct but upon inspection (`whos`) is seems b is just an instance of class foo that shows the value of 1. I tried ovarloading subsref which works with `b = a()` and  `b = a(1)` but `b = a` still doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I did not fully get the question. Don't know how to achieve what you want.